# Running a powershell on multiple python threads

Tags: python, powershell

I have a Backup software made in Python. This backup software lists all the computers on a network and I need to backup the computers to a given directory. My thought was: When the user click on backup on a certain computer, it launches a Thread where a Powershell script is executed and the percentage ((Bytes Copied / Total Bytes to be Copied)*100) is displayed. Everything works fine and I'm able to copy a single computer without problem.

But here's the problem: Whenever I launch a second thread (I click backup on another Computer), it seems like the process from Powershell stops as there's no more output and the only running process is the new Powershell process launched on the second thread.

Thread run method:

```py
     def run(self):
        '''
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        '''
        self.setAlive(True)
        p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",".\script.ps1 . .\\Backups"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.signals.progress.emit(self.CurrentComp['RowIndex'], 0, self)
        percentage = 0.0
        a = ""
        displayPercentage = 0.0
        while a != "Done Copying":
            a = p.stdout.readline()
            a = a.decode("utf-8").strip()
            try:
                percentage = float(a)
                print(percentage)
                while displayPercentage != int(percentage):
                    displayPercentage += 1
                    sleep(0.03)
                    self.signals.progress.emit(self.CurrentComp['RowIndex'], displayPercentage ,self)
            except ValueError:
                pass

        self.signals.finished.emit()
```

```bsh
Param([String[]]$paths,[String]$Destination)

function Copy-WithProgress {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $Source
        , [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [string] $Destination
        , [int] $Gap = 200
        , [int] $ReportGap = 2000
    )
    $RegexBytes = '(?<=\s+)\d+(?=\s+)';
    $CommonRobocopyParams = '/MIR /NP /NDL /NC /BYTES /NJH /NJS';
    $StagingLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy staging.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');
    $StagingArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /L {3}' -f $Source, $Destination, $StagingLogPath, $CommonRobocopyParams;
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $StagingArgumentList -NoNewWindow;
    $StagingContent = Get-Content -Path $StagingLogPath;
    $TotalFileCount = $StagingContent.Count - 1;
    [RegEx]::Matches(($StagingContent -join "`n"), $RegexBytes) | % { $BytesTotal = 0; } { $BytesTotal += $_.Value; };
    $RobocopyLogPath = '{0}\temp\{1} robocopy.log' -f $env:windir, (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss');
    $ArgumentList = '"{0}" "{1}" /LOG:"{2}" /ipg:{3} {4}' -f $Source, $Destination, $RobocopyLogPath, $Gap, $CommonRobocopyParams;
    $Robocopy = Start-Process -FilePath robocopy.exe -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Verbose -PassThru -NoNewWindow;
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
    #region Progress bar loop
    while (!$Robocopy.HasExited) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $ReportGap;
        $BytesCopied = 0;
        $LogContent = Get-Content -Path $RobocopyLogPath;
        $BytesCopied = [Regex]::Matches($LogContent, $RegexBytes) | ForEach-Object -Process { $BytesCopied += $_.Value; } -End { $BytesCopied; };
        #Write-Verbose -Message ('Bytes copied: {0}' -f $BytesCopied);
        #Write-Verbose -Message ('Files copied: {0}' -f $LogContent.Count);
        $Percentage = 0;
        if ($BytesCopied -gt 0) {
           $Percentage = (($BytesCopied/$BytesTotal)*100)
        }
        Write-Host $Percentage
    }
    Write-Host "Done Copying"
```

Comment: "it launches a Thread where a Powershell script is executed" - except that's not what you're doing - you're spinning up a thread that then calls `subprocess.Popen()`, spawns a new `powershell.exe` process which then in turn spawns `robocopy.exe` - so now you have multiple process trees doing the same thing against the same file system target (you always pass `.` and `.\Backups` as source and dest)

Comment: So that means that if the source path is different, it will work properly?
Also I wanted to know if there is a way to pass an array from Python to Powershell? I got a Path Array that I'd like to pass to the subprocess that would then do the robocopy?